# SQL: group function is not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.ID = B.ID AND COUNT(B.*) < 4
WHERE A.STATUS = 0
```

In `tablea`, ID will have 2 row of data(2 entries), but in `tableb` the same ID will have upto 4 rows of data. I am trying to get the ID that has less than 4 rows of data in `tableb` and display that result.

so if ID 12345 is having only 2 rows of data in `tableb`, display that result. IF ID 98765 has 4 rows of data in `tableb`, ignore this entry.

But when i try the above query it says `"group function is not allowed here"`. Please can someone help.

Comment: join to a sub query
``
SELECT * FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN (SELECT B.ID, Count(B.Id) As Count FROM TABLEB B GROUP BY B.Id) C ON A.ID = C.ID AND Count < 4
WHERE A.STATUS = 0
``

Comment: @SujeshArukil thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

You can not use `count()` without `goup by` or `having` clause. In your case you need `having`

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.ID = B.ID 
WHERE A.STATUS = 0
having COUNT(B.*) < 4
```

see the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8db7/1)

Comment: hah!  You state that you "cannot use count() without group by." then show a solution (INcorrect by the way) that does just that!  You CAN use aggregate functions without a `group by`, as long as they will operate on the entire data set returned by the query, and there are no non-aggregate expressions in the select clause.  Your answer fails because select * includes all attributes in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

write it the way you would say it...

"I am trying to get the ID that has less than 4 rows of data in tableb and display that result"

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA a
    JOIN TABLEB b ON b.ID = a.ID 
WHERE A.STATUS = 0
   and (Select count(*) from TABLEB 
       where id = a.Id) < 4
```

it's not clear, but if you also only want Ids which have 2 or more rows in TableA:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA a
   JOIN TABLEB b ON b.ID = a.ID 
WHERE A.STATUS = 0
   and (Select count(*) from TABLEB 
       where id = a.Id) < 4
   and (Select count(*) from TABLEA 
        where id = a.Id) > 1
```